# Is it possible to change Windows 7 Taskbar to behave like Vista?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

So I've tried the Windows 7 SuperBar in Production for 2 months, and I car surely say that I don't like it, it slows me down a LOT.

So I've tweaked it by enabling small icons and never combine them, but it is still a step back from vista:

- New items don't open at the end of the tasks if they belong to an open program. Open an Explorer Window, open another program, then open another explorer window - it will be put in the middle, before the other program
- The icons are not equally sized. Due to the grouping, the whole layout is asymmetric (My Taskbar is 2 rows high) which not only looks annoying, but can make finding a window harder
- All related icons light up. If you have 8 open explorer windows and hover over one, the whole taskbar lights up like a Christmas tree.

Is there any way to get the Vista behavior back, which means removing the "Related Windows belong together" nonsense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are some tips for you to **[Make the Windows 7 Taskbar Work More Like Windows XP or Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/make-the-windows-7-taskbar-work-more-like-windows-xp-or-vista/)**.

- Right-click on a blank area of the taskbar and, remove the checkmark from the item "Lock the taskbar; if there is"
- Right-click on a blank area of the taskbar and select "Properties" from the context menu
- Put the checkmark next to "use small icons"
- Select "Never combine" from the drop-down menu located near the "Taskbar buttons" and click OK
- Right-click on each icon on the taskbar and select "Unpin this program from taskbar" from the context menu
- Right-click an empty space on the taskbar and select "Toolbars -> New Toolbar from the contextual menu
- Go to the %SystemDrive%\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Mic rosoft\Internet Explorer\
- Highlight the "Quick Launch" and click the button "Select Folder"
- Right-click on the Quick Launch bar and remove the check mark from the items "Show Title" and "Show Text"
- Drag the Quick Launch bar on the left of the taskbar, next to the button start
- Right-click an empty space on the taskbar and if you wish, put the checkmark in the "Lock the taskbar".

If you want the old Quick Launch back: **[How to Enable or Disable Quick Launch in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/888-quick-launch-enable-disable.html)**

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't resolve the main issue sadly, which is "Keeping related windows together" :(

Comment: yep, i know ... unfortunately some useful features of older Windows versions fell victim to what the nice folks at Microsoft consider 'progress' :( you can 'fine tune' the taskbar with 7 Taskbar Tweaker: http://rammichael.com/?proj=29

Comment: That seems awesome, the "Grouping" section seems to be exactly what I need. I'll check it out this evening.

Comment: That Tweaker did the trick, disabling the grouping is it.