# Turn off tabbed browsing: Chrome/Firefox - Is it possible?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

Is it possible somehow to revert back to the *old browsing habits*, i.e. no tabs in Chrome or Firefox?

*I stumbled the web but I cannot find the answer to this question.*

Comment: @terdon when I work I have at most 3 windows opened per desktop (I use Dexpot) and simply the tab bar is occupying too much space taken in the account the taskbar is nearly empty ;-)

Comment: So you want to disable the tab bar, not tabbed browsing?

Comment: @techie007 Yes, I have to admit my question is a duplicate.

Comment: @laika No worries, that's the way it goes. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no native option in Chrome or Firefox to turn tabs off, but you can find Extensions or addons to have a workaround feature.

Hiding Tab Bar in Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-tab-bar-with-one-tab/

A few quick searches didn't turn much up for chrome extensions that has something similar, but it's likely there is something out there.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to hide the tab bar, you can do it with the [TabMixPlus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) firefox add-on:

[image]